# Link-checker issue in CQ for broken URLs when images components are inserted in anchor tags

Tags: aem

I was using the image component inside anchor tags and found if the URL of the anchor tags is broken then the link-checker functionality kicks in and marks it with an image , an opening brace image and a closing brace image. But the closing -brace image goes missing if the component put inside the anchor tags is an image component .
Below is the code of the component.

```html
<div class="" style="background-color:#79a0c1">
    <a href="http://http://www .goo gle.  Com">
            <cq:include path="image" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/image"/>
    </a>    
</div>
```

Below is the screen shot of the error
[image: image showing the issue]

Comment: why do you have to cq:include the entire image component ? the OOTB image component itself is capable of functioning as a link. Still if you want a customised component , why not move the image configuration to the dialog where you are capturing the link ? cq:include is runtime include.

Comment: @Sharath, I agree with your explanation. What shown here is just a part of the actual problem. I have many such components where in -->there are several <div></div> tags inside one anchor tag(<a></a>) . Each of these div tags have individual cq:include tags and they include an image a plain text etc.

Comment: When I got to the root of the problem I could see that only image component is causing this issue. But for plain text it works fine. I have raised this issue with Adobe - support team as well. Is there an official adobe documentation that say this type of coding is incorrect. So that I will take-up with the entire dev-team to do a big code change in many of the existing components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This issue was due to improper configuration setting for the entire application.
This is the configuration having incorrect settings.
Config.auth—>
com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerTransformerFactory with following properties

linkcheckertransformer.disableChecking—> false
linkcheckertransformer.disableRewriting—> false
linkcheckertransformer.mapCacheSize—> 5000
linkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements—> a:href,,area:href,form:action,img:src
linkcheckertransformer.strictExtensionCheck—> false
linkcheckertransformer.stripHtmlExtension—> false

We have the same configuration even for Config.publish

Removed the above configuration from both author and publish, then the issue got resolved
```